# How to use Jeep format in report documentclass?

Tags: formatting, document-classes

I was asked to use the Jeep format for writing my report but I can't seem to find any documentation on the subject. I was able to import jeep in my documentclass like this `\documentclass[12pt,jeep]{report}` but my IDE says it's an unused import and there was no change in the document. How can I format my document using Jeep styling?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  I'm not familiar with Jeep.  Could you elaborate on what that is?  Also, I'm not sure what you mean by "I was able to import" but "it's an unused import".  My understanding is that you can have `\documentclass[anything]{report}` and it won't cause an error.  So just because you were able to have `jeep` there doesn't mean it worked.  Or have you done something else to import jeep?

Comment: There is `jeep.sty` on CTAN, but it's a LaTeX 2.09 style and, before 1993, it could be enabled by `\documentstyle[12pt,jeep]{report}`. But that was 30 years ago and I doubt that `jeep.sty` can be used with current LaTeX.

Comment: @Teepeemm Jeep is apparently a document style like APA or IEEE but I was asked to do it this way by a professor, but I have no clue and my research on the subject yielded no results.

Comment: Try with `\usepackage{jeep}`.

Comment: @egreg I just tried it with `\usepackage{jeep}` pdflatex says it can't find jeep.sty. Should I install it manually?

Comment: @FabioMatos The file `jeep.sty` should be somewhere LaTeX can find it and is not included in the standard distributions. You can download it from CTAN and keep it along your `.tex` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I downloaded `jeep.sty` and `jeep.tex` from CTAN. Then I modified the first line in the latter file to

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{jeep}
```

and ran `pdflatex jeep`. To my surprise, the documentation file produced output and no error.

However, you should keep in mind that the last update to `jeep.sty` was done in December 1991 and that, in the meantime, LaTeX 2.09 has been declared obsolete.

There's no guarantee that `jeep.sty` works without faults, even if errors are not shown. As far as I can see from the documentation, it's a collection of customization that can be done with more modern packages.

With LaTeX 2.09 one could import the style file with

```
\documentstyle[jeep,<other styles>]{<main style>}
```

and this is still supported by the current LaTeX, although it should not be used for new documents: the support is there so older documents typeset also with the new format.

Comment: It actually worked. I know I should not generate a new documents with this format (in fact I never will), I just need it for a class. Thanks. P.S I manually installed the package in ubuntu/Debian following this [guide](https://jvgomez.github.io/pages/manually-install-latex-packages-in-ubuntu.html).